# cant write file since API 28

Tags: java, android

I write some logs to a file, since API 28 i get a permission error, the rights
"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" are grandet.
what can i do?

```
public static void writeToFile(StringWriter data)
{

    final File path =
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (
                            //Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/test"
                    );


    if(!path.exists())
    {

        path.mkdirs();
    }

    final File file = new File(path, ERROR_FILE);



    try
    {

        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();

        }

        Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);
        fw.write(currentTime+" "+"\n");
        fw.write(data.toString());
        fw.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(!path.exists())
    {

        path.mkdirs();
    }`. No good code. Check if the directory is made. `if ( ! path.exists()){if ( ! path.mkdirs() ){Toast(mkdirs failed); return;}}` Please tell what happens.

Comment: Also file.createNewFile(); returns a value. So check that! Please adapt your code.

Comment: Do you have defined permissions that you are using inside `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using api level >= 28 then there's a new permission attribute is added for accessing storage by android which you will add in you manifest and also don't forget to add read write permissions to manifest.

```
<manifest >
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" >
    ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Change file path to this,

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
```

and then create file,

```
public static void createFile(){
        try {
        File file = new File(dir, "example.txt");
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and if you want to write to file,

```
//Write to file
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) {
fileWriter.append("Writing to file!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Handle exception
}
```

Hope this helps

Thanks.